# Get Epoch timestamp accurate by the day with datetime

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I want to get a day-accurate (not hour, minutes, seconds) Epoch timestamp that remains the same throughout the day.

This is accurate by the millisecond (and therefore too accurate):

```
from datetime import date, datetime
timestamp = datetime.today().strftime("%s")
```

Is there any simple way to make it less precise?

Comment: *"too accurate"* - what do you mean by that? Milliseconds resolution just specifies a precision - that does not mean that the timestamp is *accurate*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UNIX timestamp is by necessity accurate to the (milli)second, because it's a number counting seconds. The only thing you can do is choose a specific time which "stays constant" throughout the day, for which midnight probably makes the most sense:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

timestamp = datetime.now(timezone.utc).replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0).timestamp()
```

Comment: "*it's a number counting seconds*" - does this specify an accuracy? To me, that's just a resolution that allows a certain precision in the representation of date/time.

Comment: Yes, sure, it doesn't have a *resolution* which is coarser than a second.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what do you want.

If you just want a quick way, either use `time.time_ns()` or `time.time()`. Epoch time is used by system (on many OS), and so there is no conversion. The `_ns()` version avoid floating point maths, so faster.

If you want to store it in more efficient way, you can just do a:
(`int(time.time()) % (24*60*60)` so you get the epoch at start of the day. Epoch contrary most of other times (and GPS time) has all days long 24*60*60 seconds (so discarding leap seconds).